# Hibernate, PostgreSQL - column of relation does not exist

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

I want insert data from my login/register form to table using Hibernate and PostgreSQL, I'm using only java config, NO XML. I'm using PoolingDataSource. When I click "Register" button it gives me this error - **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "firstname" of relation "userx" does not exist**

**Eclipse Error:**

```
    Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:library-project' did not find a matching property.
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.8
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Apr 27 2018 19:32:00 UTC
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         9.0.8.0
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\jre
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_171-b11
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Deny\Documents\WORKSPACESTS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Deny\Documents\WORKSPACESTS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Deny\Documents\WORKSPACESTS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1250
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin;C:\Users\Deny\Documents\maven-3.3.9\MAV\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Users\Deny\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Deny\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\Deny\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\Deny\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Deny\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Deny\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Deny\AppData\Roaming\npm;;C:\Users\Deny\Desktop\sts-bundle\sts-3.8.3.RELEASE;;.]
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1045 ms
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:33 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.8
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:36 ODP. org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:36 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:37 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:37 ODP. org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:37 ODP. org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Aug 01 12:15:37 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:37 ODP. org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Registering annotated classes: [class com.library.config.SpringConfig]
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:38 ODP. org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:39 ODP. org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.3.Final}
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:39 ODP. org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:39 ODP. org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:39 ODP. org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:40 ODP. org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:40 ODP. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:40 ODP. org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry register
INFO: HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@3278d065
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:42 ODP. org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFO: Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.library.controllers.Controllers.getHome(org.springframework.ui.Model)
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:42 ODP. org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register
INFO: Mapped "{[/saveUser],methods=[POST]}" onto public void com.library.controllers.Controllers.saveUser(com.library.entity.User)
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:42 ODP. org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:42 ODP. org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter initControllerAdviceCache
INFO: Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Aug 01 12:15:37 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:43 ODP. org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager afterPropertiesSet
INFO: Using DataSource [org.postgresql.jdbc2.optional.PoolingDataSource@760a2b6e] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:43 ODP. org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 6140 ms
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:43 ODP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:43 ODP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:43 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 9653 ms
Hibernate: insert into userx (email, firstname, lastname, password) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:50 ODP. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:50 ODP. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ERROR: column "firstname" of relation "userx" does not exist
  Pozice: 27
Srp 01, 2018 12:15:50 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/library-project] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "firstname" of relation "userx" does not exist
  Pozice: 27
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.postgresql.ds.jdbc23.AbstractJdbc23PooledConnection$StatementHandler.invoke(AbstractJdbc23PooledConnection.java:455)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.performInsert(AbstractSelectingDelegate.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2840)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3411)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:619)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:644)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:636)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:631)
    at com.library.dao.UserDaoImpl.saveUser(UserDaoImpl.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.saveUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.library.service.UserServiceImpl.saveUser(UserServiceImpl.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.saveUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.library.controllers.Controllers.saveUser(Controllers.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:412)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1385)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Spring Config:**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.library")
@PropertySource("classpath:persistance-postgresql.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");   }



    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
                = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource(){
        PoolingDataSource source = new PoolingDataSource();
        source.setServerName(env.getProperty("jdbc.server"));
        source.setDatabaseName(env.getProperty("jdbc.name"));
        source.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
        source.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        source.setInitialConnections(getIntProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize"));
        source.setMaxConnections(getIntProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize"));

        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.library.entity");
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactoryBean;

    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect");
        return properties;
    }

    private int getIntProperty(String name){

        String prop = env.getProperty(name);
        int propVal = Integer.parseInt(prop);

        return propVal;
    }


}
```

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class Controllers {

    @Autowired
    UserService service;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getHome(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        return "login";
    }

    @PostMapping("/saveUser")
    public void saveUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
        service.saveUser(user);
    }


}
```

**UserDAO**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory factory;

    @Override
    public void saveUser(User user) {
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(user);
    }

}
```

**persistance.properties**

```
    #
# JDBC connection properties
#
jdbc.server=localhost
jdbc.name=library
jdbc.user=postgres
jdbc.password=111

#
# Connection pool properties
#
connection.pool.initialPoolSize=5
connection.pool.minPoolSize=5
connection.pool.maxPoolSize=100
connection.pool.maxIdleTime=3000
```

**login.jsp**

[login.jsp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpBA3.jpg)

**User class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="userx")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email
                + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }


}
```

**and my DB table:**

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlP73.jpg)

Comment: You left out the most important part. Your `User` entity. Also your database schema.

Comment: Please share your User class

Comment: Just added User entity, pls look.

Comment: typo : your schema is fisrtname fiRSTname, if you can't correct the database, you can change your class annotation

Comment: yes, I just realized it while I took the screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, its my stupid mistake, It's just a typo, I created column with name - "fisrtname". Sorry for wasting your time.